# How to block an IPSEC VPN yet allow a VOIP phone

Tags: vpn, ipsec

How can I block VPN apps on my home network but allow my VOIP phone to continue to work?  From what I can tell, the VPN app in question uses IPSEC, but when I block that in the firewall, it prevents my IP phone from working.

My phone is using IPv4 configuration.  The firewall came from my ISP, and I have some level of security control which seems to be by service/service port(IPSEC, PPTP, L2TP etc.)  It allows me to do port forwarding and DMZ Hosting.  If there is a way to control things by IP address, I'm not sure what that would be called or how to set it up.  Here are the menu categories in the Firewall UI:

Firewall
Port Forwarding
Applications
DMZ Hosting
Advanced DMZ
UPnP
NAT

Comment: If you have control over IP assignment you could selectively block which devices have access to what services.

Comment: It is unknown what firewall you are using, how VPN blocking is implemented in this firewall and which VoIP protocol you are using (SIP, H.323, XMPP, Skype, ...). Therefore propose to close it as too broad.

Comment: unfortunately we can't troubleshoot your router's config for you with this level of detail - even if you get to the required level of detail, it becomes a router config question which is off-topic here